# Having trouble simulating orbits in Visual Python

Tags: python, vpython

This is the code i have written in VPython so Far, I'm new to Vpython and i'm not that experienced in python so cut me some slack please,  The error I get is:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Makka Pakka\Documents\Planetary Orbits.py", line 28
>     SUVAT(EarthInitialV,Distance)   File "C:\Users\Makka Pakka\Documents\Planetary Orbits.py", line 4, in SUVAT
>     EarthFinalV.x = sqrt((A.x) + 2*Acceleration*(B.x)) TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'vector'
> ```

```
from visual import *

def SUVAT(A,B):
        EarthFinalV.x = sqrt((A.x) + 2*Acceleration*(B.x))
        EarthFinalV.y = sqrt((A.y) + 2*Acceleration*(B.y))
        EarthFinalV.z = sqrt((A.z) + 2*Acceleration*(B.z))

GravitationalConstant = 10

Sun = sphere(pos=(0,0,0), radius=10, color=color.red,
             make_trail=True)

Earth = sphere(pos=(50,0,0), radius=5, color=color.yellow,
               make_trail=True)

Sun.mass = 50
Earth.mass = 10

EarthInitialV = vector(5,5,5)
EarthFinalV = vector(0,0,0)

while 1 != 2:
    Distance = Earth.pos - Sun.pos

    GravitationalEquation = (GravitationalConstant*Sun.mass*Earth.mass)*Distance / mag(Distance)**3
    Acceleration = GravitationalEquation/Earth.mass

    SUVAT(EarthInitialV,Distance)

    Earth.x.pos = Earth.x.pos + EarthFinalV.x
    Earth.y.pos = Earth.y.pos + EarthFinalV.y
    Earth.z.pos = Earth.z.pos + EarthFinalV.z
```

Comment: What issue in particular are you running into? What are you observing with the above code? Answering these in your Question will help get more responses.

Comment: Oh sorry i for got to include that, ill edit it now

Answer (score 0):

Besides the physics equations not being correct,
the error is caused by adding a number (a component) and a vector (3 components). To make it work, you need to rewrite the function as

```
def SUVAT(A,B):
    global EarthFinalV
    EarthFinalV = sqrt((A) + 2*Acceleration*(B))
```

Then in the `while` loop (why not say `while True:`) after `SUVAT`, replace the 3 statements with

```
Earth.pos = Earth.pos + EarthFinalV
```

Spheres have attributes `Earth.pos` (vector), or `Earth.pos.x` (a component), but not `Earth.x.pos`.

Anyway, your code should run, but the physics needs correction.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me, the code did work

Comment: Accept the answer, then :)